# Tension as a function of distance from the centre of a rod AB rotating about its end A

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotation

My confusion is-

1) While taking limits, tension at end B of rod is taken 0, The function comes showing maximum Tension at end A.

But it seems to me that that at end A, T must be 0 as x=0 and at end B it must be max.
Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [A rod of length  L  & mass  M  is rotating in a circle about one end then calculate tension in the rod at a distance  x  from the support](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64803/)

Comment: Read this: [Find Tension of the rotating rod at a distance x](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/find-tension-of-the-rotating-rod-at-a-distance-x.642166/) and see how the tension depends upon the distance as $(L^2-x^2)$

Comment: If the tension at x = 0 were zero, the rod would not fly off if you let go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tension force at any point in the rod provides the force that keeps the parts of the rod further from the centre of rotation moving in a circle.  For points closer to the centre there is more mass to swing around i.e. a larger centripetal force is required, so the tension is larger.

I'm assuming your thinking of a rod rotating in a horizontal plane.  In a vertical plane the tension will be more when B is below A and less when is above.  You could even get compression in the rod if it's rotating slowly enough.